# NavLink renders as it should, but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, styled-components

I got a little problem with using NavLink. My code:

```
<Navigation>
   <li>
      <NavLink exact to={routes.home}>Home</NavLink>
   </li>
   <li>
      <NavLink exact to={routes.aboutMe}>About Me</NavLink>
   </li>
   <li>
      <NavLink exact to={routes.projects}>Projects</NavLink>
   </li>
</Navigation>
```

I use it with styled-components, so I also share my Navigation component here

```
const Navigation = styled.ul`
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    li{
        margin-top: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;

            &.active {
            color: white
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

So the main problem is that everything works properly until I don't try to press that button to change my view, it's not clickable. That's how React renders that in browser

```
<ul class="sc-hiSbYr gKppz">
   <li>
      <a aria-current="page" class="active" href="/">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/aboutMe">About Me</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I tried styling NavLink using

```
const NavElem = styled(NavLink)
```

I also tried styling NavElem using

```
<NavElem as={NavLink} exact to={routes.home}/>
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

React has a built-in library for routing, it's called react-router.
Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router

With this library, you can set your routes to work properly using standardized components for it.
For example, you don't have to make your own NavLink component with href, since you got the { Link } component from the library.
So you will use it like this:

```
<Link to="/exampleRoute" exact component={"ExampleComponent"} />
```

Please consider watching some videos about react router or following any tutorial before using it.

Comment: but I use react-router, NavLink is a part of react-router-dom, Link but used to use it in Navbar

Comment: Did you set the routes for the following pages you want to switch (/home, /aboutme/, /projects)? Routes are often set in your App.js file with using react router.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, routes are set. Here's Root.js file:

```
<Router>
   <GlobalStyle />
   <MainTemplate>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path={routes.home} component={Home}/>
         <Route exact path={routes.aboutMe} component={AboutMe}/>
         <Route exact path={routes.projects} component={Projects}/>
      </Switch>
   </MainTemplate>
</Router>
```